# Which layout to use for git-svn in a project with standard layout currently and non standard layout in past

Tags: git, git-svn

Should I use standard layout param (`-s`) for git svn when our subversion repository adheres to standard layout currently although it was not the case for most of the history?

I'm trying to import the subversion repository into git with while history.

More details

First few years the main project folders were in the root instead of trunk folder

```
/ - project folders in root
  '- e.g. apps
  '- components
/branches
/tags
/trunk - empty
```

After many years a migration branch was introduced and used for few additional years

```
/ - project folders in root
  '- e.g. apps
  '- components
/branches
  '- migration - a long living branch used as main project work for some time
      '- e.g. apps
      '- components
  '- few other branches (<3)
/tags
  '- many tags for releases
```

For the past one year the current state conforms to standard layout

```
/ - no files, no folders in root (except trunk, branches, tags)
/branches
  '- oldMigration - migration branch renamed (moved)
      '- e.g. apps
      '- components
  '- few other branches (<5)
  '- oldRoot - folders from the root moved here
/tags
  '- around 150 tags for releases
/trunk
  '- e.g. apps
  '- components
```

**UPDATE** Just to clarify, going forward we do not plan to work (commit/checkout) with the oldMigration and oldRoot anymore. It is just that we want the history to reflect the situation how it was for the purposes of reading history log and see who changed which files and why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this situation, you can feed git-svn multiple directories which represent trunk, branches and tags to cover all the possibilities throughout history.

I would recommend doing it in two steps, `git svn init` and `git svn fetch`, rather than a single `git svn clone` to give yourself a bit more control.

In your case it would be...

```
git svn init --trunk=trunk/ --trunk=. --branches=branches/ --tags=tags/ ...
```

You may wish to try `--trunk=branches/migration`, but honestly I would leave that as its own historical branch (presumably later merged into the new trunk) than trying to get Git to pretend it was trunk all along.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Do you think we should still add the root as trunk because it was used like this in past even though it is not the case anymore?

Comment: @devmake I'm a huge fan of having complete history, never know when it will be needed.  It (probably) doesn't hurt so why not?  On the other hand, depends on why you're using git-svn.  If it's just to make working with an SVN repository easier, you probably don't need perfect history, but again, why not when you can have it just as easily?  But if you're *converting* an SVN repository to Git, I'm a huge fan of complete history conversions.  Otherwise you never know if the Git repository contains the whole story and have to keep the old SVN repository hanging around.

Comment: We are migrating from Svn to Git, we want to forget about Svn repo and have complete history in Git. (The migration with history hurts but we still want it.) I'm just not sure what is the best way to transform the history - the most important flow was \ (root) -> \branches\migration -> \trunk (created as a copy of the \branches\migration as trunk was empty at that time). I like to keep migration as branch if git is capable of showing the file changes just fine.

Comment: @devmake Keep in mind that branches in Git don't work like in SVN.  They work like actual branches in a tree.  So long as git-svn can recognize that the root branch is the parent of the migration branch is the parent of trunk it should be fine.  If it can't, you can fix that in Git after the conversion.  In the end, doing the conversion is relatively cheap, just let it run overnight or something. Try a few configurations and see how it goes.

Comment: Unfortunately it took almost two days for us. Some time was lost because we had to start git svn fetch after an error but anyway it is not a fast process ideal for too many experiments so I really appreciate your input.

Comment: @devmake Run them all in parallel.  But honestly, you don't have to fret too much so long as you have all the content.  Branches can be made to connect together later in Git.